# compare two EntityManagerFactories for having PersistenceUnits with identical connection attributes

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Having two JPA2 (EclipseLink) `EntityManagerFactory` instances what would be the best way to detect that their PersistenceUnit attributes are identical?

Answer (score 0):

You can call getProperties() to get the persistence unit properties and compare them.

Normally EclipseLink will use the same EclipseLink ServerSession if the same persistence unit is used twice.  You can call unwrap(Session.class) to get the session, and see if they are the same.

Comment: getPropperties() returns just eclipselink.??? properties from persistency.xml, but not the properties defining the connection: data source, conneciton url, user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're best hit would be to get (somehow, someway, ...) access to the [`PersistenceUnitInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html) interface which is implemented and created by the container and passed to the JPA provider. The JPA provider uses it when creating the `EntityManagerFactory`.